# A reflection after a Java interview: Inheritance and polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

The following code:

```
class Base{}

class Agg extends Base{

   public String getFields(){
    String name="Agg";
    return name;
   }
}

public class Avf{
   public static void main(String args[]){
   Base a=new Agg();
   //please take a look here
   System.out.println(((Agg)a).getFields());  // why a needs cast to Agg? 

  }
}
```

My question is:  why we can't replace  `((Agg)a).getFields()`  to `a.getFields()`?  Why we need to type cast on `a`？ And I mention that `getFields()` is not defined in class `Base`, thus class `Agg` does not extend this method from its base class. But if I defined method  `getFields()` in class `Base`, 
like:

```
class Base{
    public String getFields(){
        String name="This is from base getFields()";
        return name;
    }
}
```

everything would be all right. Then 
        **((Agg)a).getFields()  is equivalent to a.getFields()**

In the code

```
Base a=new Agg();
```

Does this line means `a` has the reference of `Agg()` and a can invoke directly the method of class `Agg`. But why is there difference if I do not define the method `getFields()` in class `Base`?   Can any one explain this to me?

Comment: So, what is the question again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> `System.out.println(((Agg)a).getFields());  // why a needs cast to Agg?`

Because `Base` doesn't have a method called `getFields`.

The declaration

```
Base a;
```

...tells the compiler the interface you're going to use when using `a`. It doesn't matter that you then assign `new Agg();` to it, the *interface* you have to `a` is still `Base`. And since `Base` doesn't have `getFields`, trying to use `getFields` is a compilation error.

> `Base a=new Agg();`
>
> Does this line means `a` has the reference of `Agg()` and a can invoke directly the method of class `Agg`.

It means `a` *contains* a reference to an `Agg` object, but the interface to that object is defined by `Base`, not `Agg`, and so you can't call `Agg` methods on it if they're not defined by `Base` (without a cast, and casts are dangerous and should be avoided where possible).

If your code needs access to methods or fields defined by `Agg`, then the variable (or argument, in my example) should be declared `Agg a`, not `Base a`.

This is a fundamental thing about OOP in general and the OOP implementation in Java in particular: There's a big difference between the *interface* to an object and the *implementation* of the object. In your example, you know `Base a` is really an `Agg`, but consider this:

```
void foo(Base a) {
    // Use `a` here...
}

// A long time later in a class far, far away...
xyz.foo(new Agg());
```

Clearly here the compiler shouldn't allow you to use methods or fields on `a` that aren't defined by `Base`. It's the same situation in your code, just less obvious.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: why we can't replace ((Agg)a).getFields() to a.getFields()? why we need to type cast on a?

It sounds like you understand this really - the compiler wouldn't find a `getFields` method on the compile-time type of `a` (which is `Base`), therefore it would raise a compile-time error.

It seems like this is the *real* guts of the question:

```
 Base a=new Agg();
```

> Does this line means a has the reference of Agg() and a can invoke directly the method of class Agg. But why is there difference if i do not define the method getFields() in class Base? Can any one explain to me?

It means that the compiler will only allow you to access members of `Base`, as that's all it *knows* to be available. If there are multiple methods with the same name, *overload* resolution is also applied to the compile-time type.

However, at execution time, you're actually calling the methods on an object of type `Agg` - so if `Agg` *overrides* a method declared in `Base`, that implementation in `Agg` will be used.

Basically, you need to differentiate between decisions which are made at compile time based on the compile-time type of an expression, vs decisions which are made (by the JVM) at execution time based on the execution-time type of an object that a value refers to.

Answer (score 1):

The line `Base a=new Agg();` means
1 - local variable `a` belongs to type Base
2 - there is a new object of type Agg
3 - variable `a` references that object
The object and the variable have different (but compatible) types.
Since the variable a has the type Base, there is no a.getFields()
But since the variable references an object of class Agg, you can cast it to Agg and access getFields
A variable is (somehow like approximate sort of) a pointer to an object, and not an object.

Answer (score 1):

Because type `Agg` is a more concrete type of `Base`. Type of `a` in your declaration is `Base`. What is in left side of declaration represents the type of an object. Actually `a` contains method `getFields()`, but because it is upcasted, the method is hidden in the type `Base`. I recommend you [HeadFirstJava](http://www.amazon.de/Head-First-Java-Mike-Loukides/dp/0596009208) book. It helps you to clear out these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

An **instance** of a **Class** has access to its methods (defined in the class definition) and methods of its superclass (ex. Object class).  Therefore instance of **Class Base** with reference variable "a", can not access method getFields(). It's neither defined in its class structure **or** its super class. When you [typecast](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting) like below:

```
((Agg)a)
```

You are basically changing changing the type from (Base) to type (Agg). Agg which is a subclass of Base, defines method getFields().